# Create drawable resources from base64 data before compilation

Tags: android, resources, base64

I have an xml with base64-encoded images that I want to put as resources before compilation so that the creation of the drawables doesn't have to be done every time the app is run.

Anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not possible. You can't create resources at runtime :/